# C Programming Input Validation for checking if entire string is alphabet

Tags: c, validation, user-input, do-while

I have working code when i just test `char[] = "Gabriella"`. However, I need to get user input. Getting the input from the user breaks my code and I do not understand why.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    printf("We have recieved your order! Please enter your shipping information.\n");
    //FIRST NAME
    char *first;
    int flag = 1;
    
    do {
        printf("Your first name:\n");
        scanf (" %s", first);
        for (int i = 0; first[i]!= '\0'; i++){
            printf("here");
            if (isalpha(first[i]) != 0)
                continue;
            else
                flag = 0;
        }
    }while( (flag = 0)? printf("That is not a valid option, try again! "):0);
    
    printf("flag: %d", flag);
    printf("You have entered: %s\n", first);
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting no errors in the console, it just scans for the name and returns nothing, even with the bottom print statements.

Comment: Don't use `scanf`, use `fgets` instead. And his `while (... printf() )` construction is ugly, that code is hard to read. Try to use a "less intelligent" version, one that is easy to read and understand.

Comment: What does `first` point to? Where did you set it to point to that?

Comment: What does `(flag = 0)` do? How does it differ from `(flag == 0)`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `first` is a pointer but it does not reference valid memory location and it is an Undefined Behaviour
2. Use functions!

```
int validate(const char *str)
{
    while(*str && isalpha(*str++));
    return *str;
}

char *getString(char *buff, size_t maxlen, FILE *fi)
{
    char *result;
    if((result = fgets(buff, maxlen, fi)))
    {
        size_t len = strlen(buff);
        if(len && buff[len - 1] == '\n') buff[len - 1] = 0;
    }
    return result;
}

#define MAXFISRTNAME    20

int main()
{
    printf("We have recieved your order! Please enter your shipping information.\n");
    //FIRST NAME
    char first[MAXFISRTNAME];
    
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Your first name:\n");
        if(getString(first, MAXFISRTNAME, stdin))
        {
            if(!validate(first)) break;
            printf("\nYou entered wrong name\n");
        }
    }    
    printf("You have entered: \"%s\"\n", first);
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/szrofd6Wd

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with strings can be a hard concept in C. As there is no built in string type as in other languages you have to learn to deal with zero terminated character arrays.

The definition char *first defines a pointer to char. If you want to go that direction then you need to allocate enough memory to hold your string. See [malloc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/malloc?view=msvc-170).

The reason char[] = "Gabriella" works is because you've defined a complete zero terminated string but that method cannot be used to get data input.

Try changing `char *first` to `char first[80]`. That way you will have created space big enough to hold an 80 character string and you'll be able to use it as is in your current code.

For more detail on how strings work in C see [Working with strings in C](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strings-in-c/)